# Show that $a\rho b\iff a^4b^2-4b^2=b^4a^2-4a^2$ is equivalence relation and deduce classes

Tags: analysis, logic, equivalence-relations

I think I've solved problem, but I need to check it.

**Problem**: On $\mathbb{R}$ is given relation $a\rho b\iff a^4b^2-4b^2=b^4a^2-4a^2$. Prove that this is equivalence relation and deduce equivalence classes of elements $0$, $\frac{1}{2}$, $-2$.

**My solution**: I proved that this relation is reflexive, symmetric and transitive and therefore is equivalence relation, but I have to check equivalence classes. I got that $[0]=\{0\}$, $[\frac{1}{2}]=\{\pm \frac{1}{2}\}$, $[-2]=\{\pm 2\}$. Am I right?

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

**P.S.** Is there any shorter way to conclude that this is equivalence relation and to deduce classes of equivalence?

Comment: I assume one of those $4a^2$ should be a $4b^2$ or you'd just have cancelled it from both sides.

Comment: @MatthewDaly Yes, I edited question.

Comment: @Calvin Lin Thanks, I made a mistake in calculation.

Comment: @CalvinLin I fixed it, thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that $a^4b^2-4b^2=b^4a^2-4a^2 \Leftrightarrow a = \pm b$.

Clearly the latter is an equivalence relation, with elements of the same absolute value.